# Java classpath and config file

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm having some trouble finding a config file with classpath.

I use :

```
InputStream stream = myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("properties.file");
```

The properties.file is located under config directory.

When running the program with eclipse, it works.
I just added config folder in the classpath in the launch configuration.

But If I want to run the exported jar like this :

```
java -jar -cp C:\project\lib;C:\project\config myclass.jar
```

I get the oh wonderful `java.lang.NullPointerException` because it can't find the file.

This sounds classic and stupid but I can't find a clue.
What does eclipse do that I don't ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use absolute path for class (If you don not want to put the properties file in your jar relative to the class)

```
InputStream stream = myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties.file");
```

or simply

```
InputStream stream = myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties.file");
```

And then ensure that the path to the dir containing this resource file is specified in the classpath when you run the jar so that the systemclassloader will be able to find this resource.

Answer (score 1):

when you launch jar file using `java -jar` it ignores the classpath specified by `-cp`

**See:**

- [How to add classpath entry for a jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 1):

In order for your Exported `Jar Files` to access your `resources`,

1. `Right Click` your Project in **Eclipse**
2. Select `New -> Source Folder`, now name this `Source Folder` as, say `resources`
3. Now manually add your `config folder` to this folder through `File System`
4. Now go back to your **Eclipse** `Right Click` your Project and Select `Refresh`

Now one can see the added folder inside the `Project Tree`. Now in order to access the contents of your config Folder write this :

```
InputStream stream = myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/config/properties.file");
```

Comment: Yes this will work (did something like this before), but then as a source folder, it will be added to the build path and then packaged into the jar file. So if I want to change parameters in my properties file I'm stucked because the program uses the one in the jar :(

Comment: @user1228291 : Eclipse automatically adds that to your classpath also, I guess, with this as you run your Project, do check your bin/classes folder, whatever stuff was inside your resources Folder will be added to bin/classes folder. Ahha, now I understood, you are right, seems like :-) But providing absolute file path is also not a good idea, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the config file in your jar, you could pass the path to the config-file as a command line argument to your application.

```
java -jar myclass.jar C:\project\config
```

and then load the file by absolute path

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String pathToConfig = args[1]; //or 0/2, check to see
   String configFilePath = pathToConfig  + "/properties.file";
   String[] lines = FileUtil.ReadLines(configFilePath);

}
```

But I recommend against it, since you are going to have a tough time deploying. The file must exist at the target and you have to potentially start your program differently each time.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. That's why I wanted to be able to tell Java "ok, look for properties.file in the folders I told you with classpath". So that it will look inside config directory and find the file.

In fact, I even wanted to be able to run : java -jar myclass.jar my_properties_file, and java would look through every folders in the classpath and would find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `java -help` you will see the following USAGE:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)
>   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)

So maybe you will need to fix the command as follows:

```
java -cp C:\project\lib;C:\project\config -jar myclass.jar
```

You can also try the following:

```
java -classpath C:\project\lib;C:\project\config -jar myclass.jar
```

Or even setting the classpath before running your program:

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\project\lib;C:\project\config
java -jar myclass.jar
```