# Properties File is not accessible from Java Class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, properties

i am building web application using servlet, jsp and java class.

Herewith the java structure

[image: project structure]

I want to access the `system.properties` file as that file is storing project configuration.

What i do is getting the file using `FileInputStream` using this java code

```
/* generate the properties file objects */
Properties prop = new Properties();

/* generate IO to read from properties file */
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("system.properties");
if (inputStream != null) {
/* load the properties file */
    prop.load(inputStream);
```

the putting all the variables from the file into object

`host = prop.getProperty("host");`

But it shows error `nullpointerexception` as i know the parameter from the properties file is not loaded.

```
Apr 26, 2015 7:21:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.domain.servlet.TotalErrorSummaryServlet] in context with path [/MonitoringDashboard] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any suggestion to edit the loader for the `system.properties` file? As i put the file in the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Put `system.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes` and add a `/` in `getResourceAsStream("/system.properties")`

Comment: Try `InputStream inputStream = class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/system.properties");` instead your `inputStream`.

Comment: If the properties file is not accessible you'd get an exception when you do `prop.load()` can you log the value of host after getProperty?

Answer (score 0):

I just can think of one thing, and that is you didnt put your properties file in your class path, for checking that put some logs inside your `if` statement like below:

```
if (inputStream != null) {
    //some logs here 
    prop.load(inputStream);
}
else {
    //and some logs here 
}
```

you could see that your input stream is null and nothing get loaded to your `prop`, and as I could see you are using `eclipse` so use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412909/java-classpath-and-config-file/9413026#9413026)

Comment: But his log4j properties is in the same location and seems to be getting picked up fine?

Comment: @RaGe We have no way of knowing if that log4j file is being picked up or not. To load a file as a resource it must be on the class path, and it's unlikely the OP has changed the container so it includes a non-standard directory. As asked, this is almost certainly the answer.

Comment: @Rage what i found here is the java project is cannot load the properties file from the folder specified. I have try to create new resources folder then access from that, but still no luck, the properties file cannot loaded.

Comment: @DaveNewton i have try to put the else statment in inputStream != if function. but seems that the file is not populated altough i have change the system.properties to another resources folder.